# Is it possible to cast template parameters on runtime?

Tags: c++, templates, casting

Given the following templated method

```
template <typename T>
T max(T x, T y)
{
    return (x > y)? x : y;
}
```

I want the following call to work:

```
int main()
{
    cout << max(3, 7.0) << std::endl; //compiler error
}
```

I understand that the compiler fails due to the fact that I'm passing 2 different datatypes while my template only accepts 2 parameters with same type.
The easiest solution would be using polymorphism and creating a new template method that uses type T and X instead of 2 types T but I want to ask you if there's a way to make some sort of cast of parameter y to the type of parameter x without modifying the call in main()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not exactly clear from your question what type you expect `T` to be in this scenario, but if you want it to be e.g. the type of the first argument, then you can make the second parameter a *non-deduced* context:

```
template <typename T>
T max(T x, std::type_identity<T>::type y)
{
    return (x > y)? x : y;
}
```

`std::type_identity` is a C++20 feature but its implementation is really simple:

```
template<typename T>
struct type_identity {
    using type = T;
};
```

Everything left of the scope resolution operator in the parameter is non-deduced, so the whole parameter is non-deduced context and will not participate in template argument deduction. Instead normal implicit conversions will be applied in overload resolution.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

that fails because of template's type deduction which fails to deduce between `int` and `double`, you could either explicitly specify the template type, use two template parameters or cast it inside to `T` with `static_cast`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that by creating another template method:

```cpp
template<class T, class U>
T max(T x, U y) {
    return max(x, static_cast<T>(y));
}
```

Note: If it's just about max, use `std::max` from the STL.

Comment: I know I could create another method with the same name in order to achieve the solution (I wrongly described it as polymorphism instead of overloading in my post). I was wondering if there could be other tricks to achieve the same solution. I'm trying to prepare myself for a job interview and I expect them to ask me even the  strangest solutions to a given problem

Comment: I'm going at a tangent here, but this solution would produce different results for max(3, 3.5) and max (3.5, 3), which I think is counter intuitive.